# Inconsistent results when counting Kafka records using ksqldb and confluent-kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb, confluent-kafka-python

I wish to count the number of records in a given Kafka topic to set up a monitoring endpoint as a kind of 'sanity check' for data-in vs. data-out.

I noticed that doing this with confluent-kafka 1.9.2 produces results that differ from those produced by e.g. ksqldb.

The source topic is partitioned, has **infinite** retention and is not compacted.

When trying to process the number of records with `confluent-kafka 1.9.2`:

```py
from confluent_kafka.admin import AdminClient
from confluent_kafka import Consumer, TopicPartition

consumer = Consumer({"bootstrap.servers": BROKER_URI, "group.id": GROUP_ID, "isolation.level": "read_committed"})

def seek_to_offset(consumer: Consumer, partitions: List[TopicPartition]):
    for current_partition partitions:
        current_partition.offset = -2  # earliest

    consumer.assign(partitions)


def get_topic_size(topic_name: str = DEFAULT_TOPIC):
    consumer.subscribe([topic_name], on_assign=seek_to_offset)
    total_record_count = 0
    while True:
        record = consumer.poll(30.0)  # default session timeout
        if record is None:
            log.debug('No more records')
            break
        if record.error():
            log.error(f'Consumer error: {record.error()}')
            continue

        total_record_count += 1

    consumer.close()
    return total_record_count

log.info(f'Number of records: {get_topic_size()}')

Number of records: 61316573
```

The result is `61316573`.

On the other hand, I have a `confluentinc/ksqldb-server:0.28.2` together with `confluentinc/ksqldb-cli:0.28.2` running that is supposed to also tally the number of records for a similar check. I do that as follows:

1. I set the ksql consumer isolation level to `read_committed` so that I only get committed messages and the processing guarantee to `exactly_once`. Prior to running the below queries, I set `auto.offset.reset` to `earliest`:

```yaml
# As environment variables in my ksqldb service via docker-compose
---
version: '2'
services:
  primary-ksqldb-server:
    image: confluentinc/ksqldb-server:0.28.2
    hostname: primary-ksqldb-server
    container_name: primary-ksqldb-server
    environment:
      # ... 
      KSQL_KSQL_STREAMS_PROCESSING_GUARANTEE: exactly_once
      KSQL_KSQL_STREAMS_CONSUMER_ISOLATION_LEVEL: read_committed
```

This is the recommended way of passing this configuration when starting via docker according to the [documentation](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/operate-and-deploy/exactly-once-semantics/#default-for-all-queries-and-non-interactive-headless-mode).

Lastly, inside `ksqlDB`:

```bash
ksql> set 'auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest'
```

2. I created a stream based off my topic.

```bash
ksql> create stream mytopic with (kafka_topic='mytopic', key_format='KAFKA', value_format='AVRO');
```

3. I created a table to sum up the number of records based on a timestamp field in the record (`creationdate`):

```bash
ksql> create table mytopic_count_per_date with (kafka_topic='mytopic_count_per_date', partitions=18, replicas=1) AS 
    select count(*) num_records, TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(mytopic.creationdate, 'yyyy-MM-dd') date
    from mytopic mytopic
    group by TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(mytopic.creationdate, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
    emit changes;
```

The output of this table looks as follows:

```bash
ksql> select * from mytopic_count_per_date;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|DATE                                                                           |NUM_RECORDS                                                                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|2022-04-04                                                                     |2260363                                                                        |
|2022-04-06                                                                     |2407432                                                                        |
|2022-04-27                                                                     |915754                                                                         |
|2021-12-22                                                                     |6                                                                              |
|2021-12-31                                                                     |16                                                                             |
...
```

4. Lastly, *after waiting for the above table to be fully up-to-date and not have any consumer lag*, I created another table that sums up these grouped per-date values:

```bash
ksql> create table mytopic_total with (kafka_topic='mytopic_total', partitions=18, replicas=1) AS
    select sum(mytopic_count_per_date.num_records) total_records, 'x' X
    from mytopic_count_per_date mytopic_count_per_date
    GROUP BY 'x'
    EMIT CHANGES;
```

Aggregate functions for pull-queries are unfortunately not supported, hence the need to do it like this.

I expected the `total_records` column in my `mytopic_total` table to contain the exact same value that I got using `confluent-kafka` above. However, I get a different value:

```bash
ksql> select * from mytopic_total;
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
|X                                     |TOTAL_RECORDS                         |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
|x                                     |61316958                              |
```

---

Since I can't tell the faulty source apart with just two data sources, I tried a third approach using `kcat` (note that the `librdkafka` default isolation level is also `read_committed`):

```bash
$ docker run edenhill/kcat:1.7.1 -C -b broker:9092 -o beginning -f '%o\n' -u -t mytopic -e -G kcat-console mytopic | wc -l
61316573
```

### Thus it seems like the result of `confluent-kafka` i.e. Python is correct, and `ksqldb` is not.

The versions I am running are:

- `confluent-kafka: '1.9.2', 17367552` / `librdkafka: '1.9.2', 17367807`
- `ksqldb-server: 0.28.2` / `ksqldb-cli: 0.28.2`
- `kcat: 1.7.1` / `librdkafka: '1.8.2'` (according to [GitHub](https://github.com/edenhill/kcat/blob/1.7.1/bootstrap.sh#L14))

My questions are:

1. Why is the `ksqldb` value different? Are there other configuration options that I have to enable in `ksqldb`? Is this a bug?
2. In step 4 above I waited for the first table to be fully-up-to-date before trying to sum up the grouped terms. Is this always necessary? I saw that the result differed when I did not do this.

Comment: _set the ksql consumer isolation level to read_committed so that I only get committed messages and the processing guarantee to exactly_once_ - What exact  properties did you set? Also, keep in mind, that records could actively be removed from compaction or retention, so you should not "count records" very frequently. Your "sanity check" should rather monitor JMX ingest rate to the topic/broker without actually consuming records to do so...

Comment: I added some clarification to the question w.r.t. your remarks. The source topic has infinite retention without compaction, so compaction/deletion should not play a role here. Re: *should rather monitor JMX ingest rate*: I was under the impression that the only way to get a precise reading on the actual number of records in a topic written to by a transactional producer, is to actually consume and count the records. Is this not the case? I'm all for a simpler solution, if there is one...

Comment: To add on the above: the plan is to use the data contained in the topic for reporting/aggregations of invoice data (when/what/how much) later on, and so the requirement is for this data to be verifiably exact. The sanity check described above was the simplest way I could find to *repeatably* and *verifiably* check that the data is complete.

Comment: Okay, well, in my experience, counting of consumed records will be slower-and-slower over time using any client (let's assume your consume restarts). I think it'd be better to dump the topic to a database or file storage, then count from there.

Comment: I think we're misunderstanding each other. I don't restart counting the records. The consumers may restart, sure, but the idea was to still compare with a pre-computed tally from the source topic after (re-)ingestion was done.

Comment: *I think it'd be better to [...]* That's kind of what I was going for in using ksqlDB - keep a table of the current tallies using a push query and compare vs. transferred data to e.g. AWS. On the AWS side we could easily query the count using e.g. Athena, but that still doesn't help me in ascertaining the number of records that *should* have been transferred. And dumping the topic into another non-streaming DB kind of defeats the purpose of using Kafka in the first place, I would think...

Comment: There are streaming databases, but I guess you are creating a stateful stream rather than always counting from the beginning, so assuming the `group by` works as expected (what if `creationdate` is null?), then I suggest opening a Github issue in KSQL

Comment: Yes, I am creating a stateful stream and not recounting past records everytime. Re: `creationdate` - the record field is fortunately guaranteed to be non-null. Either way, thanks for the suggestion. For the record, I've gone ahead and heeded it ([ksql#9650](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/9650)). I'll update this post if/when I learn something new there.

Comment: One thing I noticed - `exactly_once` config option... Are you setting this anywhere in librdkafka configs? Or maybe this is the default? Basically, seems to me that KSQL is not skipping over some transaction markers, perhaps, and there is a different config needed for that, so it is counting extra/duplicate records. Also, you should try `v2`?  https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/operate-and-deploy/exactly-once-semantics/